# Bootstrap container always appears fluid?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn Bootstrap 3 and I am stuck. I have 3 columns of 4 rows using 4 different Bootstrap colors. My code looks like this

```
<div class= "container">
<div class= "row">
<div class= "col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-warning">
```

With the closing div tags and repeated 12 times just changing the colors.

The problem is that when run, it always appears fluid, taking up the entire width of the screen and never stacking when I reduce the screen size. Somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0):

While attempting to edit your question to fix the broken code segment, the answer became immediately obvious (as will be shown by the syntax highlighting). You've used a double quote instead of an equals sign in your class declaration for your third line.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class= "row">
    <div class" "col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-warning">
```

Should be:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-4 bg-warning">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi Obsidian Age, Thank You.  Sorry about that. The error only appears in my question and not in my actual code.

Comment: No problem, although the code above (that I've posted, and you say you already have) is valid Bootstrap to do what you're attempting to (have one column on a large screen and three columns on a small screen). If it doesn't work for you, then the problem is likely the fact that you've forgotten to include the **Bootstrap CDN**. How are you loading Bootstrap into your HTML? It requires **both** a JavaScript and CSS file. Could you please confirm that you've loaded it correctly, and try to post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: Hi Obsidian Age, I copied and pasted the CDN links from the Bootstrap website. I will review and post them here mañana, getting late here. Stack overflow has instructed me not to say thanks. So Cheers.

Comment: If you have the links in your `<head>` correctly, there should be nothing wrong with your code. I'd recommend trying to create a fiddle on BootPly where you can test your problem, and then updating your question to link to that. It's also strange that people here told you not to say thanks -- there's nothing wrong with saying it. In fact, it's courteous. You get some really weird people here sometimes ;)

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"

Comment: Above are the 2 links I have in the head. I don´t know a fiddle from a diddle but I will try to figure that out.  It actually says in the window that opens when I click add comment  ¨Avoid comments like +1 or thanks.¨  I don´t want to break the rules so I will just say Gracias.